# how to get value from a drop down list on onchange event using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, struts2-jquery

I have a struts2-jquery drop down list where different data is available to select.
If users select any data, then am sending the select box value. 
Now my new requirement is how can i send the id of the list instead of the value from the list.

Please check my below code and suggest me a good solution for my problem.

index.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 $(function(){
    $("#selectthemeid").change(function(e){
            var param = $(this).val(); 
            alert(param); //this is giving me my selectbox value but i want the selectbox  ID i.e (listKey="id")

         });  
 }); 
</script> 

     <sj:select   
      name="theme"    listKey="id"
      listValue="themeName" id="selectthemeid"  />`
```

**Generated html  output from my above struts2 selectbox**

```
 <select name="theme" id="selectthemeid" theme="jquery" keynav:shortcut="36">  
    <option value="68">black-tie</option>
    <option value="69">blitzer</option>
    <option value="70">cupertino</option>
    <option value="71">dark-hive</option>
 </select>
```

*What i want is*: 
  **i want the id of my row i.e 68**  (`<option value="68">`) currently from my above code i am getting the value of the select box  i.e. black-tie  (`<option value="68">black-tie</option>`)               `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.id

```
 var id = this.id; //using javascript, will give performance benefit.
 id = $(this).attr('id'); //using jQuery
```

if you want to access other attribute of select e.g `listKey`

```
listKey = $(this).attr('listKey');
```

Comment: i tried the both bot its not giving me the id. First one(` id = $(this).attr('id');`) is giving me the id of my select box i.e. selectthemeid (`...listValue="themeName" id="selectthemeid"  theme="jquery"/>`)      AND second one is giving output like `undefine`

Comment: i want the values which are residing in here `listKey="id"` .Currently my above code is giving me correct value which are residing inside the `listValue="themeName"`  . This is a single row data where `listKey="id"` gives the id of the row and   `listValue="themeName"` gives me the value of that row.

Comment: That is all you have for now. Are you looking for attributes on options of select, I am not clear what you want then. Can you show me generated html and point out what you want?

Comment: I updated my genearted html code above please see it. Now i guess  you are clear about my problem.  My problem : i want the id of my row i.e 68  (`<option value="68">`) currently from my above code i am getting the value of the select box  i.e. black-tie  (`<option value="68">black-tie</option>`)

Comment: You do not have id with option but value that you should be getting by val(), although I made a demo for you here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9KZ26/

Comment: yeah i got it .. why i was getting error because i kept some extra code in my selectbox. i removed it and now i am getting the expected result.